# Ruby on Rails 3 - Get name of view calling helper

Tags: model-view-controller, variables, view, ruby-on-rails-3.1, helper

I am trying to create my own helper which will render specific content based on a view. A view with the name "large" for instance, I want my helper to render a large image using something like `<%= smart_image "image" %>` will render `<img src="image_large.jpg" />`

I need a way of passing the view's name to the helper. Because of the complexity of this Rails project, I have over simplified my requirements above. I don't want a solution like "pass the views name through a parameter" because that will not work in my project, I need it to be automatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **action_name** to get the name of the action (and the name of the view).

Comment: This answer is misleading: A controller action can render any view. Action name and view name are two different things that match in most cases, but not in general.